# Show G is NOT countably generated.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

I am having a bit of trouble understanding this question and how to begin. If I could get a bit of a nudge in the right direction I would be very grateful.

> Suppose $\Omega$ is uncountable and let G be the $\sigma$-field consisting of sets $A$ such that either $A$ is countable or $A^c$ is countable.
>
> Show $G$ is NOT countably generated. (Hint: If $G$ were countably generated, it would be generated by a collection of one-point sets.)

Comment: See this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1486269/36150

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume it is countably generated by a set $\{A_0\cdots , B_0, \cdots \}$ where $A_i$ is countable and $B_i^c$ is countable then consider $\Omega -\bigcup A_i\cup B_i^c$. The elements of this set cannot be separated.

Answer (score 2):

Let $S=\{A_n\}_{n\in N}$ where each $A_n$ is a countable or co-countable subset of $\Omega.$ For $n\in N$ let $B_n=A_n$ if $A_n$ is countable, and $B_n=A_n^c$ if $A_n$ is co-countable. Let $B=\cup \{B_n\}_{n\in N}.$ Let $F=\{x\subset \Omega : x \supset B^c \lor x\subset B\}.$ Then $F$ is a $\sigma$-field on $\Omega$ and $F\supset S.$ So the $\sigma$-field generated by $S$ is a subset of $F$. Now $B$ is countable so $B^c$ is not empty. Observe that $\Omega$ \ $\{p\}$ belongs to $G$ but not to $F$, for any $p\in B^c.$