# From disintegration to conditioning

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

There is a paper ["Conditioning as disintegration" by J. T. Chang and D. Pollard](http://www.stat.yale.edu/%7Ejtc5/papers/ConditioningAsDisintegration.pdf), which seems to construct the [regular conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_conditional_probability) from the [disintegration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disintegration_theorem). In particular, from Definition 1, Theorem 1 and Theorem 2.(iii) in that paper, we can summarize a theorem as follows:

> **Theorem.** Let $\Omega$ be a Polish space, $\mathcal F = \mathcal B(\Omega)$ be the Borel $\sigma$-field for $\Omega$, and $\mathbf P$ be a probability measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$. Let $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space, with $\mathcal E$ countably generated and containing all the singleton sets. Let $X:(\Omega,\mathcal F) \to (E,\mathcal E)$ be a random element. Denote by $P_X := X_*\mathbf P = \mathbf P\circ X^{-1}$ the pushforward measure of $X$ on $(E,\mathcal E)$. Then there is a family $\{\mathbf P^x\}_{x\in E}$ of probability measures on $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$, such that:
>
> - For every $x\in E$, the probability measure $\mathbf P^x$ concentrates on the event $\{X = x\}$.
> - For all $A\in\mathcal F$, the mapping $\mathbf P^\cdot(A): (E,\mathcal E)\to [0,1]$ is measurable.
> - For all $A\in\mathcal F$ and $B\in\mathcal E$,
>   \begin{equation}
>     \mathbf P\left(A\cap X^{-1}(B)\right) = \int_B \mathbf P^x(A) P_X (dx).
>   \end{equation}
>   Moreover, the family $\{\mathbf P^x\}_{x\in E}$ is uniquely determined up to an almost sure equivalence: if $\{\mathbf Q^x\}_{x\in E}$ is another family of probability measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$ that satisfies above conditions, then
>   \begin{equation*}
>     P_X\{x\in E: \mathbf P^x \ne \mathbf Q^x\} = 0.
>   \end{equation*}

---

Here is the **problem**.

Consider the special case that $E=\Omega$ and $\mathcal E$ is a sub-$\sigma$-field of $\mathcal F$ that contains all singletons. [Since $\Omega$ is second countable, its Borel $\sigma$-field $\mathcal F$ must be countably generated and contain all singletons](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2456416/what-is-a-countably-generated-sigma-algebra-cant-find-a-definition-online). As a sub-$\sigma$-field of $\mathcal F$, $\mathcal E$ is also countably generated. Let $X = \mathrm{Id}$. Then $P_\mathrm{Id} = \mathbf P$ and $\sigma(\mathrm{Id}) = \mathcal E$. Now all assumptions in the theorem are fulfilled. Hence, we get a $\mathbf P$-a.s. unique family of probability measures $\{\mathbf P^\omega\}_{\omega\in\Omega}$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$ satisfying:

1. For every $\omega\in\Omega$, the probability measure $\mathbf P^\omega$ concentrates on the singleton $\{\omega\}$.
2. For all $A\in\mathcal F$, the mapping $\mathbf P^\cdot(A): (\Omega,\mathcal E)\to [0,1]$ is measurable.
3. For all $A\in\mathcal F$ and $B\in\mathcal E$,
   \begin{equation}
     \mathbf P\left(A\cap B\right) = \int_B \mathbf P^\omega(A) \mathbf P (dx).
   \end{equation}

---

The statements 2 and 3 are completely the same as the formulation of [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution#Measure-theoretic_formulation), that is, $\mathbf P^\omega(A) = \mathbf P(A\mid \mathcal E)(\omega)$. However, if we combine them with the statement 1, then there are something quite strange. Indeed, since $\mathbf P^\omega$ concentrates on $\{\omega\}$, we have $\mathbf P^\omega(A) = \mathrm{1}_A(\omega)$ for all $A\in\mathcal F$, while this should hold only for $A\in\mathcal E$ since $\mathbf P^\omega$ is the conditional probability by statement 3. Besides, the mapping $\mathbf P^\cdot(A) = \mathrm{1}_A: (\Omega,\mathcal E)\to [0,1]$ is measurable only for $A\in\mathcal E$, but not for all $A\in\mathcal F$ claimed in statement 2.

---

So where does it go wrong? Any comments or hints will be appreciated. TIA...

---

**EDIT:** Here are some further remarks:

1. I just claimed that "as a sub-$\sigma$-field of $\mathcal F$, $\mathcal E$ is also countably generated". This is wrong. See e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1486241/does-a-sub-sigma-algebra-of-a-countably-generated-sigma-algebra-have-to-be) for a counterexample.
2. Thanks to the comment by @aduh, the problem reduce to whether it must be $\mathcal E = \mathcal F$? Or does there exist a proper sub-$\sigma$-field of $\mathcal F$ that is countably generated and contains all singletons? I post this as [another question in Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3834480/exists-countably-generated-mathcal-f-s-t-sigma-omega-omega).

---

**Conclusion:** Under my assumptions, $\mathcal E$ must coincide with $\mathcal F$. So the problem is trivial. See the accepted answer given by @GEdgar in the ["another question"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3834480/exists-countably-generated-mathcal-f-s-t-sigma-omega-omega) I mentioned for details.

Comment: It's not true that $\mathcal E$ is c.g. if $\mathcal F$ is. How do you know that your assumptions don't entail that $\mathcal E = \mathcal F$?

Comment: @aduh Thank you for your comment. I am not sure if it must be $\mathcal E = \mathcal F$. I post another question for this in the site. Please see the EDIT part at the end.

Comment: Right, good. And it looks like GEdgar's answer solves the problem. In your case, $\mathcal E = \mathcal F$.

Comment: @aduh Yes, I see. Thank you and enjoy this discussion!

Comment: You might consider writing an answer to this question so that it’s not left unanswered.

Comment: @aduh I agree that it is better to have an answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Dreamer Thank you for your question. I am reading that paper as well and I feel like I understand Definition 1, Theorem 1 and Theorem 2. However in the paper (using your notation) they express property 3 as
$$
\int g d\mathbf{P} = \int \int g d\mathbf{P}^x d P_X

$$
for some measurable function $g$. This differs from what you wrote, but I have seen your version multiple times. My guess is that your expression can be derived from the one above (or in the paper) as a special case, but I am struggling to prove it. For instance, maybe I should take $g = \mathbb{1}_{A\cap X^{-1}(B)}$?

Comment: @Euler_Salter Yes exactly. Take $g(\omega) = \mathbf 1_{A\cap X^{-1}(B)} (\omega) =\mathbf 1_A (\omega) \mathbf 1_B (X(\omega))$. Then use change of variable $x=X(\omega)$.

Comment: @Dreamer Ahh I see. The LHS then would be 
$$
\int g d\mathbb{P} = \int \mathbb{1}_{A\cap X^{-1}(B)}(\omega) d\mathbb{P}(\omega) = \int_{A\cap X^{-1}(B)} d\mathbb{P} = \mathbb{P}(A\cap X^{-1}(B))
$$
as you correctly said

Comment: @Dreamer While the RHS would become
$$
\int\int g d P^x dP_X = \int\int \mathbb{1}_{A\cap X^{-1}(B)}(\omega) P^x(d\omega) P_X(dx) = \int\int \mathbb{1}_A (\omega) \mathbb{1}_{X^{-1}(B)}(\omega) P^x(d\omega) P_X(dx)
$$

Comment: Now I can use the fact that $\mathbb{1}_{X^{-1}(B)} = \mathbb{1}_{B}(X(\omega))$ and the fact that $P^x$ is only defined on $X^{-1}(x)$ to write $\mathbb{1}_{X^{-1}(B)} = \mathbb{1}_B(x)$ and so 
$$
\int\int g dP^x dP_X = \int \mathbb{1}_B(x) \int \mathbb{1}_A(\omega) P^x(d\omega) P_X(dx) = \int \mathbb{1}_B(x) P^x(A) P_X(dx)
$$

Comment: @Euler_Salter Perfect! ^_^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I post here an answer for integrity.

As said in the **Conclusion** part at the end of the question, we can prove $\mathcal E = \mathcal F$ following the lines of [@GEdgar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3834480/exists-countably-generated-mathcal-f-s-t-sigma-omega-omega/3834757#3834757). More precisely, we can prove the following theorem:

> **Theorem.** Let $\Omega$ be a Polish space, $\mathcal F=\mathcal B(\Omega)$ be the Borel $\sigma$-field for $\Omega$. If $\mathcal E\subset \mathcal F$ is a countably generated sub-$\sigma$-field containing all the singleton sets, then $\mathcal E = \mathcal F$.

The theorem is trivial as long as we know the following lemma, which is adapted from Theorem 3 and Theorem 1 in the [paper of D. Blackwell "On a Class of Probability spaces"](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bsmsp/1200502002), as well as the two facts that a Polish space is [analytic](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Analytic_set) itself and that the atoms in a Polish space are nothing but singletons.

> **Lemma.** Let $\Omega$ be a Polish space, $\mathcal F=\mathcal B(\Omega)$ be the Borel $\sigma$-field for $\Omega$. If $\mathcal E\subset \mathcal F$ is a countably generated sub-$\sigma$-field, then a set $A\in\mathcal F$ belongs to $\mathcal E$ if and only if $A$ is a union of singletons.